# No sound output device on boot

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a problem with the sound on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Basically, on every boot, I lose all my output devices and I am forced to run `rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k`, then reboot, to make the sound work again. It's been a long time that I had this issue. I tried a lot of Linux distros and the only one that didn't seem to cause problems to my sound was MX Linux because it was booting using sysvinit. All the other distros based on Ubuntu that used systemd were causing this problem. [image: sound settings]

Here is my neofetch

[image: neofetch]

I tried to restart alsa, pulseaudio, to reinstall them, to install pavucontrol, but non of these solutions worked.

Is there a way to solve the problem without having the delete the pulse config then having to reboot every time? Thank you